# How to know which solution is physical?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, projectile, displacement

When solving the expression for displacement of an accelerating object and solving for the time variable:
$$v_it+\frac{1}{2}at^2=d$$
$$v_it+\frac{1}{2}at^2-d=0$$
$$t=\frac{-v_i\pm \sqrt{v^2_i+2ad}}{a}$$
$$t=\frac{-v_i\pm v_f}{a}$$
where $a$ is acceleration, $t$ is time, $v_i$ is initial velocity, $v_f$ is final velocity, and $d$ is displacement.

How do I know if I should choose + or - on the last step?  Is there a way do select the physical solution without any additional information?

Comment: How did you get to use $v_f^2 = v_i^2+2ad$?  I would have thought $v_f=v_i+at$ was much more natural

Comment: @Henry I got $v^2_f=v^2_i+2ad$ from a Physics book. $v_f=v_i+at$ also works.

Comment: $v_f=v_i+at$ works better in this case, since it gives a single value for $v_f$ and so for $t$.

Comment: @Henry the radicand in the third step contained $v^2_f$. I didn't find any natural occurrences of $v_i + at$ while working out the problem.

Comment: One solution is positive and one solution is negative.  Since we can't jump back into the past to observe and/or influence a physical phenomenon, only the positive answer is physically realizable.

Comment: @DavidWhite but what if both the + and - give positive solutions?

Comment: If $v_i$ is positive and $v_f$ is positive, you can't get a positive answer when you take $-v_i$ and subtract $v_f$ from it.  Check your choice of positive direction and positive velocity, and make sure that you chose consistent directions for both.  Also, if you have a case where both roots are positive, show your work so others in this forum can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: What are you trying to find? The time of flight? Or just the time for a given displacement? If the second one , then   both, since both t values give the same displacement. If you want to find the t value for a specific X and Y value, then you need to re-label D to be Y, and then write an equation of motion for the X coordinate  then sub in the x and y to find the corresponding T value

Comment: @jensenpaull So right now I'm not trying to solve for anything, just finding a new formula for time.

Comment: In that case, T is non unique as you haven't specified enough information.  Let $x=V_{x}t $ and then similarly $y=V_{y}t + 1/2at^2 $and then you can chose a value of X,y to solve for T. Because as it stands now  multiple t values correspond to the same displacement

Comment: "Is there a way do select the physical solution without any additional information?" No. The bottom line is you need some physics to decide what is physical. All you have right now is algebra.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you are solving is
$$v_i t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2 = d$$
Imagine what that means physically. You shoot a bullet up in the air, that reaches the highest point and then falls back to earth. The equation asks at what time it reaches a distance $d$ above you. It can reach that distance on the way up or on the way down, so the equation has (or can have) two solutions.

Now, in the real problem, you are not given $d$, but $v_f$. You can calculate $d$ from $v_f$, and then solve the equation. Or you can use the identity $v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2ad$ as you did. But the sign of $v_f$ also tells you whether the bullet reached $d$ on the way up or on the way down. So $v_f$ gives information about which of the solutions is correct.

Of course, it is much easier to use the relationship:

$$ v_f = v_i + a t$$

to solve that for $t$ directly, without this detour.